# How to refer broadcast variable in dataframes

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I use spark1.6. I tried to broadcast a RDD and am not sure how to access the broadcasted variable in the data frames?

I have two dataframes employee & department.

Employee Dataframe

```
-------------------
Emp Id | Emp Name | Emp_Age
------------------
1 | john | 25

2 | David | 35
```

Department Dataframe

```
--------------------
Dept Id | Dept Name | Emp Id
-----------------------------
1 | Admin | 1

2 | HR | 2

import scala.collection.Map

val df_emp = hiveContext.sql("select * from emp")

val df_dept = hiveContext.sql("select * from dept")

val rdd = df_emp.rdd.map(row => (row.getInt(0),row.getString(1)))

val lkp = rdd.collectAsMap()

val bc = sc.broadcast(lkp)

print(bc.value.get(1).get)

--Below statement doesn't work

val combinedDF = df_dept.withColumn("emp_name",bc.value.get($"emp_id").get)
```

1. How do I refer the broadcast variable in the above combinedDF statement?
2. How to handle if the lkp doesn't return any value?
3. Is there a way to return multiple records from the lkp (lets assume if there are 2 records for emp_id=1 in the look up, I would like to get both records)
4. How to return more than one value from broadcast...(emp_name & emp_age)

Answer (score 4):

> How do I refer the broadcast variable in the above combinedDF statement?

Use `udf`. If `emp_id` is `Int`

```
val f = udf((emp_id: Int) =>  bc.value.get(emp_id))

df_dept.withColumn("emp_name", f($"emp_id"))
```

> How to handle if the lkp doesn't return any value?

Don't use `get` as shown above

> Is there a way to return multiple records from the lkp

Use `groupByKey`:

```
val lkp = rdd.groupByKey.collectAsMap()
```

and `explode`:

```
df_dept.withColumn("emp_name", f($"emp_id")).withColumn("emp_name", explode($"emp_name"))
```

**or just skip all the steps and `broadcast`**:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

df_emp.join(broadcast(df_dep), Seq("Emp Id"), "left")
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.....for returning multiple records from the lookup, I did the following....val lkp = rdd.groupByKey.collectAsMap().....val bc = sc.broadcast(lkp)......val f = udf((emp_id: Int) =>  bc.value.get(emp_id))......I get java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException.

Comment: Also, if I look up has multiple columns, How to return more than one value from broadcast...(emp_name & emp_age)

Comment: There was a mistake in the udf call which is fixed. With multiple value it is best to use broadcast join (the last part).