# How to refer broadcast variable in Spark DataFrameSQL

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have the following SparkSQL:

```
val resultDf = spark.sql("SELECT name, phone, country FROM users")
```

I'd like to filter returned records by countries which are present in the following collection:

```
val countries = Seq("Italy", "France", "United States", "Poland", "Spain")
```

For example I can create the broadcast variable based on the collection:

```
val countriesBroadcast = sc.broadcast(countries)
```

but is it possible(and if so - how?) to use the `countriesBroadcast` variable inside of my SQL query?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to refer broadcast variable in dataframes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41337553/how-to-refer-broadcast-variable-in-dataframes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In spark data frame API we can broadcast the entire table can be joined with the target table to get the desired output. Here is the example code.

Imports

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.broadcast
```

Code

```
val spark = SparkSession.builder().master("local").getOrCreate()

val df = spark.read.option("header", true).csv("data/user.txt")
df.createOrReplaceTempView("users")
val countries = Seq("Italy", "France", "United States", "Poland", "Spain")
import spark.implicits._
spark.sparkContext.parallelize(countries, 1).toDF("country").createOrReplaceTempView("countries")
broadcast(spark.table("countries")).join(spark.table("users"), "country").show()
```

"data/user.txt" file contents

```
 name,phone,country
 a,123,India
 b,234,Italy
 c,526,France
 d,765,India
```

Code output:

```
+-------+----+-----+
|country|name|phone|
+-------+----+-----+
|  Italy|   b|  234|
| France|   c|  526|
+-------+----+-----+
```

Note: code tested with Spark 2.2 and Scala 2.11

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible, with exception to `UserDefinedFunctions`, `UserDefinedAggregateFunctions` and `Aggregators` (i.e. non-declarative code).

To use broadcasting with `DataFrame` / SQL API you should use `DataFrames` and use broadcast hint - [Spark SQL broadcast hash join](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37487318/).